# Help inconsistent index result on generated column after server restart

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, computed-column

I have a table that has a date column and I need a data that will be group by week. And I found this Youtube video that used an index generated column [Faster database indexes (straight from the docs)](https://youtu.be/5aezDBaNfcc?si=cctM0DzcazkkifOy) from PlanetScale.

Then I modify my table to look like this.

```sql
mysql> show create table tbl_bought_code\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tbl_bought_code
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tbl_bought_code` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `package_code` char(8) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `package_type` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `code_price` int NOT NULL,
  `bought_on` date NOT NULL,
  `bought_on_week` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (yearweek(`bought_on`,0)) VIRTUAL, -- this column was added
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `package_code` (`package_code`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `bought_on` (`bought_on`), -- this index is added
  KEY `bought_on_week_index` (`bought_on_week`), -- this  index is also added
  CONSTRAINT `tbl_bought_code_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47348 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Then I did this explain query

```sql
explain 
select sum(code_price), bought_on_week 
from tbl_bought_code 
where bought_on between DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH),'%Y-%m-01') and NOW() 
group by bought_on_week;
```

And the result is very promising.

```sql
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type  | possible_keys                  | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_bought_code | NULL       | range | bought_on,bought_on_week_index | bought_on | 3       | NULL | 6962 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

But when I **restart** the server, and re execute the explain query I got this.

```sql
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | partitions | type  | possible_keys                  | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tbl_bought_code | NULL       | index | bought_on,bought_on_week_index | bought_on_week_index | 5       | NULL | 46274 |    15.05 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

Why the explain result is different after restarting the server? Why it uses the `bought_on_week_index` index instead of `bought_on` index? The first explain query only returns 6962 rows while the second explain query returns 46274, it look like it do a full table scan.

Comment: The index selection depends on the index statistic which may be altered/refreshed. Anycase both indices are not suitable for your query..

Comment: When you say the indices are not suitable for my query, what you suggest to use, what index should I add or what should I modify on the query?

Comment: You filter your data by `bought_on` then group by `bought_on_week` then calculate sum by `code_price`. I'd recommend you to test 2 composite indices - by `(bought_on, bought_on_week)` and `(bought_on_week, bought_on)`, and also 2 covering indices - by `(bought_on, bought_on_week, code_price)` and `(bought_on_week, bought_on, code_price)`. Select those index which will show the most fast query execution (I predict that this will be 1st covering index, but this depends on the data statistic). Also remember that data changes, and another index may become more effective in future.

Comment: Does the query return the same number of rows each time?  Perhaps 6K?  By "return" I mean the output from the query _not_ what `EXPLAIN` says.

Comment: @RickJames yes if I remove the group by

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**  Not a problem.

**Long Answer:**

- In a plain `EXPLAIN`, the "rows" is an estimate.  So, the discrepancy is bogus.
- `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` will give you exact counts.  (What version of MySQL are you running?  That is a new feature.)
- `EXPLAIN` uses index statistics that are recomputed at various times.  The reboot was probably one of those times.
- Those statistics are approximate, so they are subject to random variations.
- A "cost" model is now used for deciding on the 'best' query plan.  But it is imperfect (partially due to the statistics).
- I suspect the two query plans produced identical results within nearly the same amount of time.  But the ordering of the results *may* be different.  Adding an `ORDER BY` would make them consistent and *might* force its choice of an index.

Comment: I'm sorry i need to split the comment not enough characters. I'm running MySQL 8. I tried running explain with analyze and got this on first run `Index scan on tbl_bought_code using bought_on_week_index  (cost=4907 rows=47464) (actual time=0.185..42.2 rows=47303 loops=1)`

Comment: but on the second run `Index range scan on tbl_bought_code using bought_on_index over ('2023-07-01' <= bought_on <= '2024-01-12'), with index condition: (tbl_bought_code.bought_on between <cache>(date_format((now() + interval -(6) month),'%Y-%m-01')) and <cache>(now()))  (cost=3133 rows=6962) (actual time=0.022..7.37 rows=6962 loops=1)` and I tried again without the analyze I got `6962` on `rows`. Does this mean the table index and the query is just fine, there is no need to modify it?

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, see `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and the Optimizer trace.https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#optimizer_trace